# How to implement smooth transitions between containers in WinRT?

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, expression-blend, winrt-xaml

I have a Silverlight 4 game that I'm attempting to port to WinRT. It makes heavy use of Blend's FluidMoveBehavior to animate item transitions between containers (items float from one container to another). It appears that this functionality is missing from WinRT, and I have been unable to find a substitute.

In Silverlight, this XAML does it all:

```
<ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="TransitioningPanelTemplate">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0" Background="Transparent">
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <il:FluidMoveBehavior AppliesTo="Children" Duration="0:0:0.400" Tag="DataContext">
                <il:FluidMoveBehavior.EaseY>
                    <BackEase EasingMode="EaseInOut" Amplitude="0.35" />
                </il:FluidMoveBehavior.EaseY>
                <il:FluidMoveBehavior.EaseX>
                    <BackEase EasingMode="EaseInOut" Amplitude="0.35" />
                </il:FluidMoveBehavior.EaseX>
            </il:FluidMoveBehavior>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </StackPanel>
</ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

I looked into Transitions as suggested [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12998837/is-fluidmovebehavior-available), but this appears to only work within a single container.

Is there some use of Transitions that will allow this behavior? If not, is anyone aware of possible alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="TransitioningPanelTemplate">
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0" Background="Transparent">
     <StackPanel.ChildrenTransitions>
      <TransitionCollection>
<Your Transitions />
</TransitionCollection>
</StackPanel.ChildrenTransitions>
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <il:FluidMoveBehavior AppliesTo="Children" Duration="0:0:0.400" Tag="DataContext">
            <il:FluidMoveBehavior.EaseY>
                <BackEase EasingMode="EaseInOut" Amplitude="0.35" />
            </il:FluidMoveBehavior.EaseY>
            <il:FluidMoveBehavior.EaseX>
                <BackEase EasingMode="EaseInOut" Amplitude="0.35" />
            </il:FluidMoveBehavior.EaseX>
        </il:FluidMoveBehavior>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</StackPanel>
```